# LESS CSS CDN: ERR_INVALID_URL

Tags: html, css, less

I'm new to Less, so I'm assuming that this is my fault and not the CDN.

I've got a pretty straight forward html document (less.html)

```
<html>
    <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="styles.less">
       <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" >. 
       </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <h1>This is a test</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also created a basic Less file (styles.less)

```
@color: red;

.header {
    color: @color;
}

h1 {
    color: @color;
}
```

The HTML renders with no issue, however I'm receiving an error in the console: ERR_INVALID_URL. Thus the CSS isn't working.

[image: Chrome Dev Tools Screenshot]

I copy and pasted the link to the CDN directly from Lesscss.org, so I'm assuming it's correct. Any idea why I'm getting that error code in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your screenshot you can see that the file is being called as a local file which obviously doesn't exist in your computer. Change your file url to "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/less.js/3.9.0/less.min.js" while you are working locally.

Comment: That seems to have improved the situation, but now I'm getting a cross origin request error. I think I read somewhere that this is a particular issue with Chrome, will have to compile on the command line I guess. Thanks for the assist.

Comment: Yes. That would be a way better approach. You can also consider SASS or Gulp which are really cool.